# ¿De dónde viene la palabra "perillán"?

Tags: etimología, sustantivos, adjetivos, palabras-raras

El Diccionario de la lengua recoge
[perillán, perillana](https://dle.rae.es/perill%C3%A1n?m=form):

> 1. m. y f. coloq. Persona pícara, astuta. U. t. c. adj.

e indica como etimología:

> Del ant(iguo) *Per* 'Pedro' e *Illán* 'Julián'.

sin más aclaraciones.

Por lo que he podido consultar, aparece recogida sin etimología en el Diccionario de Autoridades (1737) y los primeros usos recogidos en el CORDE son, igualmente, del primer cuarto del s XVIII.

¿Alguien puede arrojar más luz sobre esta etimología?

Comment: En la Fundéu citan esta página donde hay más información al respecto https://www.yorokobu.es/perillan/

Answer (score 4):

La palabra viene de [Per-Illán](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-Ill%C3%A1n):

> **PERILLÁN, NA.** (Etim. — De *Per-Illán*, famoso personaje toledano del siglo XIII.) m. y f. fam. Persona picara, astuta. El femenino es poco usado. U. t. c. adj.

> **PER-ILLÁN**, *Biog.* Famoso personaje toledano del sigio xiii (m. en 1217). distinguido y pundonoroso militar, llamado *Pero ó Pedro Illán* (*Petrus Juliani*), de quien se refiere que no pudiendo resistir la idea de que le pisasen después de muerto, obtuvo del rey, en premio de sus servicios, ser en¬ terrado en alto, y asi se ve hoy, en efecto, su sepulcro que se halla en la catedral de Toledo. **De él, Según afirma Terreros, «nació dar nombre de *perillanes* á los que son muy mañosos, cautos y sagaces...»** Ignórase quién era ese personaje. Sólo se conserva una curiosa inscripción latina sobre su sepulcro.

- [Enciclopedia Universal Ilustrada Europeo-Americana](https://archive.org/details/EnciclopediaUniversalVol43/page/n869/mode/2up) (tomo 43)